# Tutorial needed for GNU blackfin toolchain with Eclipse

Tags: gcc, eclipse-cdt, gnu-toolchain

Any body knows of a good tutorial on using the GNU blackfin toolchain with eclipse on Windows?

I'm trying to start with developing bare metal application on blackfin and I've installed the toolchain and eclipse C/C++ Juno but I'm unable to compile. Currently I'm getting the **make: *** No rule to make target 'all'** error but there are many other things I find myself lost at.

Many thanks in advance,

Hasan.

Edit: I've read a bit about the "make" programme, and decided to start a single-file test project to learn the command line toolchain (without the eclipse environment). Here is my main.c and associated makeFile:

```
//main.c
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    volatile int x = 42;
    printf("%i\n", x);
    return 0;
}
```

---

```
#makeFile

CPU = bf533-any
CROSS_COMPILE = bfin-elf-
CC = $(CROSS_COMPILE)gcc
LD = $(CROSS_COMPILE)gcc

CFLAGS = -c -Wall

bfin_test: main.o
    $(LD) main.o -mcpu=$(CPU) -o $@

main.o: main.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) main.c -mcpu=$(CPU) -o $@
```

---

Here is the result of running the make command on the cmd console:

```
D:\work\experiments\bfin_test_project>dir
 Volume in drive D is Data
 Volume Serial Number is 248D-2C8D

 Directory of D:\work\experiments\bfin_test_project

14/04/2013  12:30    <DIR>          .
14/04/2013  12:30    <DIR>          ..
11/04/2013  13:30               102 main.c
14/04/2013  12:29               257 makeFile
14/04/2013  12:29               264 makeFile~
               3 File(s)            623 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  634,582,650,880 bytes free

D:\work\experiments\bfin_test_project>make
bfin-elf-gcc -c -Wall main.c -mcpu=bf533-any -o main.o
bfin-elf-gcc main.o -mcpu=bf533-any -o bfin_test
c:/program files (x86)/analog devices/gnu toolchain/2012r2/elf/bin/../lib/gcc/bf
in-elf/4.3.5/../../../../bfin-elf/lib\libc.a(lib_a-closer.o): In function `close
_r':
/usr/src/packages/BUILD/blackfin-toolchain-2012R2/gcc-4.3/newlib/libc/reent/clos
er.c:53: warning: _close is not implemented and will always fail
c:/program files (x86)/analog devices/gnu toolchain/2012r2/elf/bin/../lib/gcc/bf
in-elf/4.3.5/../../../../bfin-elf/lib\libc.a(lib_a-fstatr.o): In function `fstat
_r':
/usr/src/packages/BUILD/blackfin-toolchain-2012R2/gcc-4.3/newlib/libc/reent/fsta
tr.c:62: warning: _fstat is not implemented and will always fail
c:/program files (x86)/analog devices/gnu toolchain/2012r2/elf/bin/../lib/gcc/bf
in-elf/4.3.5/../../../../bfin-elf/lib\libc.a(lib_a-isattyr.o): In function `isat
ty_r':
/usr/src/packages/BUILD/blackfin-toolchain-2012R2/gcc-4.3/newlib/libc/reent/isat
tyr.c:58: warning: _isatty is not implemented and will always fail
c:/program files (x86)/analog devices/gnu toolchain/2012r2/elf/bin/../lib/gcc/bf
in-elf/4.3.5/../../../../bfin-elf/lib\libc.a(lib_a-lseekr.o): In function `lseek
_r':
/usr/src/packages/BUILD/blackfin-toolchain-2012R2/gcc-4.3/newlib/libc/reent/lsee
kr.c:58: warning: _lseek is not implemented and will always fail
c:/program files (x86)/analog devices/gnu toolchain/2012r2/elf/bin/../lib/gcc/bf
in-elf/4.3.5/../../../../bfin-elf/lib\libc.a(lib_a-readr.o): In function `read_r
':
/usr/src/packages/BUILD/blackfin-toolchain-2012R2/gcc-4.3/newlib/libc/reent/read
r.c:58: warning: _read is not implemented and will always fail
c:/program files (x86)/analog devices/gnu toolchain/2012r2/elf/bin/../lib/gcc/bf
in-elf/4.3.5/../../../../bfin-elf/lib\libc.a(lib_a-writer.o): In function `write
_r':
/usr/src/packages/BUILD/blackfin-toolchain-2012R2/gcc-4.3/newlib/libc/reent/writ
er.c:58: warning: _write is not implemented and will always fail
```

This produced the .o and (supposedly) the elf file. And here is the result of trying to run the elf file using the toolchain simulator:

```
D:\work\experiments\bfin_test_project>bfin-elf-run bfin_test
program stopped with signal 11 (Segmentation fault).
```

According to [http://docs.blackfin.uclinux.org/doku.php?id=toolchain:sim](http://docs.blackfin.uclinux.org/doku.php?id=toolchain%3asim), this should be running the simulator in the virtual mode. (Not sure if I should be providing other files)

Also I'm not sure if the output file (bfin_test) is actually an elf file or if it can be run using the simulator (bfin-elf-run). But if so, I'm wondering why am I getting a segmentation fault of such a seemingly simple programme. Any idea anybody? Note that I get the same error when changing main to contain only "return 0;".

Could someone please tell me where I'm going wrong.

Thanks again,

Comment: Found the answer to the segmentation fault, I should specify that produced output file (bfin_test) is going to be run using the simulator tool (bfin-elf-run), so recipe of bfin_test inside the makeFile should look like this: '$(LD) main.o -mcpu=$(CPU) -msim -o $@'

Comment: Voting to close as tool recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

Hasan,

Take a look at these links. They might offer some help.

https://docs.blackfin.uclinux.org/doku.php?id=toolchain:bare_metal:compile
https://docs.blackfin.uclinux.org/doku.php?id=toolchain:bare_metal:link

It is a real struggle getting the GNU toolchain flowing for Blackfin but once you do its works pretty well.

Jim